# jQuery .get, then .each, then .css function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide all the images in my screen and display images one at a time when clicked left or right.

I know you can hide everything by using `img { display:none; }` in CSS, but I'm doing it this way (because I might want to apply different styles to each object):

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").get().each(function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
});
```

and I know this will probably throwback an error because I don't think you can use `.each()` with `.get()` this way, and it did, citing `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'each'` on the console.

How do you actually use `.get`, `.each`, `.css` and apply CSS styles to each of them individually?

Comment: Have you tried just omitting the `.get()` part?

Comment: `.get()` gets an array containing the selected elements. If you _do_ use `.get()` you can use the native JavaScript [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) .

Comment: ahh, I totally forgot $("img[class*='wp-image']") actually already selects the entire thing, and I can use `.eq()` to select them individually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to `.get()` method here. You can hide all the images:

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").each(function (index) {

    // Hide all the images
    $(this).css("display", "none");                
});
```

and apply CSS styles to each of them individually like:

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").each(function (index) {        

    // Check the index of the items
    if (index == 0) {
        // Apply specific style to first element
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    } else if (index == 1) {
        // Apply specific style to second element
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid green");
    }
    // similarly you can apply styles to each of them individually

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vTD5/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `.each()` at all. Most jQuery methods can be applied to a collection and they automatically distribute to all selected elements:

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").css("display", "none");
```

If you do need to use `.each`, perhaps because you need to make conditional changes to each element, you apply it directly to the collection:

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").each(function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove get and $each method

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").css("display","none");
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do it without the get()

```
$("img[class*='wp-image']").each(function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
});
```

you can also use hide()